# React native - facebook tracker in regular android build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tracker, duckduckgo

I have an app in production built with react native for android. There are no 3rd party plugins for tracking, logging in, or any of those sorts.

Recently DuckDuckGo app had a tool to implement others apps blocking trackers using VPN redirection.

And it comes to my attention that it is blocking now Facebook. I am not very comfortable with that and I can not find any info whatsoever on this.

Does anybody have some insight into this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that you can do is to download [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/react-native/), debug your app's network traffic with it, and see if you find any requests that are going to Facebook's servers. DuckDuckGo is probably doing the same: it monitors outgoing requests and alerts you if any requests happen to the popular data collectors, like Facebook or Google. Without you inspecting the traffic yourself, it's pretty hard to guess the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, ill try it. I'm having trouble making it work...

Comment: You'll also need the [network plugin](https://fbflipper.com/docs/setup/plugins/network/).

Comment: I can not add it because i can not select an application, is this even work with expo? I don't have much time now to investigate.

Comment: As of Expo 43 (react-native 0.63), Flipper should work.

Comment: Thanks, ill gave it another go later today.

Comment: No worries, good luck.

Comment: I have expo 42, and I'm afraid of upgrading the whole project on Mac, I managed to get devices in Flipper but react is missing from devices so it's not working..., but my question was loose so I will accept a loose answer. And it was only one. Hope to get some other opision tho in future...

Comment: You can use [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) instead of Flipper for network inspection as well.

Comment: Thanks, il check it out. There i also an issue with this method, i can only test emaultors and expo go with this, not an actual apk buid. When testing on expo it is possible for example not to have tracker active, but inserted on apk build itself. Just a possibility that I need to take into account.

Comment: You should be able to debug on actual devices not just emulators with both method as well.

Comment: Oh, good to know, thanks